# Mayavi: interpolate face colors in triangular_mesh

Tags: python, enthought, mayavi

I have pieced together the
following code to plot a triangular mesh with the colors specified by an
additional scalar function:

```
#! /usr/bin/env python
import numpy as np
from mayavi import mlab

# Create cone
n = 8
t = np.linspace(-np.pi, np.pi, n)
z = np.exp(1j*t)
x = z.real.copy()
y = z.imag.copy()
z = np.zeros_like(x)
triangles = [(0, i, i+1) for i in range(n)]
x = np.r_[0, x]
y = np.r_[0, y]
z = np.r_[1, z]
t = np.r_[0, t]

# These are the scalar values for each triangle
f = np.mean(t[np.array(triangles)], axis=1)

# Plot it
mesh = mlab.triangular_mesh(x, y, z, triangles,
                            representation='wireframe',
                            opacity=0)
cell_data = mesh.mlab_source.dataset.cell_data
cell_data.scalars = f
cell_data.scalars.name = 'Cell data'
cell_data.update()

mesh2 = mlab.pipeline.set_active_attribute(mesh,
        cell_scalars='Cell data')
mlab.pipeline.surface(mesh2)

mlab.show()
```

This works reasonably well. However, instead of having every triangle
with a uniform color and sharp transitions between the triangles, I'd
much rather have a smooth interpolation over the entire surface.

Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you want to use point data instead of cell data. With cell data, a single scalar value is not localized to any point. It is assigned to the entire face. It looks like you just want to assign the `t` data to the vertices instead. The default rendering of point scalars will smoothly interpolate across each face.

```
point_data = mesh.mlab_source.dataset.point_data
point_data.scalars = t
point_data.scalars.name = 'Point data'
point_data.update()

mesh2 = mlab.pipeline.set_active_attribute(mesh,
        point_scalars='Point data')
```

Comment: This sounds promising, but my scalar data is really per-cell rather than per point. Do I have to manually interpolate first to get the values at the vertices, or is there a way to specify point data for e.g. the cell centers rather than the vertices?

Comment: It's not clear to me that your problem is well-posed in that case. What would the interpolated value be at the peak of your example cone, adjacent to all of those faces? What algorithm would smoothly interpolate from the center, face value to that one? You may consider assigning point scalars to the existing vertices that are the averages of each adjacent cell scalar. That doesn't necessarily recreate the pure cell scalar at the center of each face, though.

Comment: Well, interpolation is by definition never unique (if that's what you mean with well-posed). Regarding the center face vs the peak vertex, I don't see the problem. While I'm plotting a 3d structure, my scalars are defined on a 2d surface, so any 2d interpolation algorithm should do just fine. Am I missing something?

Comment: Interpolation on a 2D surface still requires that the values are assigned to points, not faces. So if you can restructure your data and/or mesh such that your values are on vertices, VTK will just do it.